# ImportError: No module named appengine

Tags: google-oauth, google-app-engine-python

Following Google's [example code](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/google_app_engine#decorators) at the time of posting, the OAUTH2 decoration for the app engine client should be imported as follows:

```
from oauth2client.appengine import OAuth2Decorator
```

Attempting to import that module results in the following log error:

> from oauth2client.appengine import OAuth2Decorator
>
> ImportError: No module named appengine

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Google has moved the module but has not updated their example code.

The correct import is now:

```
from oauth2client.contrib.appengine import OAuth2Decorator
```

(Notice the `contrib` module.  Many related modules are also housed there as well.)